# Capybara failed to find position for element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, capybara, capybara-webkit

I'm using Capybara with a `webkit` driver and when I'm running tests with `js: true` it raises error listed below. When I do same things in other tests without `js: true` everything works fine.

PS. There is no need for `js :true` in this test. This code is actually inside a helper but I put it here like test , so it will be easier to understand.I'm using `js: true` in the other test that invokes this helper method.

Code below raises `Capybara::Webkit::ClickFailed:
       Failed to find position for element /html/body/div/div/div/div[2]/a[12]`

```
scenario "adding logged days", js: true do
visit '/logged_days'

find(:xpath, "//a[contains(.,'12')]").click
# click_link("12") raises same error

expect(current_path).to eq("/logged_days/new")


fill_in "Опис виконаної роботи", with: "Some description"
fill_in "Кількість відпрацьованих годин", with: 40

click_button "Додати"

expect(current_path).to eq("/logged_days")
expect(page).to have_content("40")

end
```

/logged_days:

```
   <div class="page-header">
    <h2>Logged Days <small>March</small></h2>
   </div>
   <div class="conteiner-fluid logged_days_container">
    <% for i in 1..31 %>
     <%= link_to new_logged_day_path(:cal_date => "#{i}"), method: :get do %>
      <div class="calendar_cell">
        <p class="cell_date"><%= i %></p>
        <p class= "cell_text"></p>
      </div>
    <% end %>
   <% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I had this error exactly once in all my years and it was about an element being covered or otherwise not being clickable.

A thorough investigation with your browser's webinspector is necessary here: You have to figure what your js does to that click target.

Answer (score 1):

When using js:true your page not only runs JS but also has CSS processed. This means you can end up with elements that are are non-visible, overlapped, or moving.  You need to look at what is done to the element in a real browser and make sure the element is actually clickable, or what other actions a user would have to do first to make it clickable.

Secondly, don't use .eq with current_path - it'll lead to flaky tests as you use js capable drivers. Instead use the has_current_path matcher

```
expect(page).to have_current_path('/logged_days/new')
```